# Problem with php. phpmailer and hostinger

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting, phpmailer

So i did a website in php for a group and everything is working well in xampp (if I don't use any .htaccess).

I did a contact form that sends the email directly to their email with PHPMailer and I did put the directory structure like this:

[image]

So now what I need to know is how can I add .htaccess that makes the website start automatically from the index.php but with that my form always stops working.
I tried countless things in a .htaccess, even with 2 of them (one in the public_html and another in the publix folder) ant it always messes up the form.

I leave you here the code of my form:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="../app/config/contact.php" method="POST" role="form">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nom et prénom" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.7s">
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Objet" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1.0s">
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer Message" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

My contact.php:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'config.php';

class ContactForm {
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $subject;
    private $message;

    public function __construct($name, $email, $subject, $message) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function sendEmail() {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        try {
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host = Config::$mailHost;
            $mail->Port = Config::$mailPort;
            $mail->Username = Config::$mailUsername;
            $mail->Password = Config::$mailPassword;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    
            // Set the encryption method
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // or 'tls'
    
            $mail->setFrom(Config::$mailFromEmail, Config::$mailFromName);
            $mail->addReplyTo($this->email, $this->name);
            $mail->addAddress(Config::$mailRecipientEmail, Config::$mailRecipientName);
    
            $mail->Subject = $this->subject;
    
            // Set the email content
            $mail->Body = "Nom et prenom: " . $this->name . "\n"
                        . "E-mail: " . $this->email . "\n"
                        . "Objet: " . $this->subject . "\n"
                        . "Message: " . $this->message;
    
            if ($mail->send()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// Initialize variables for message status and style
$messageStatus = '';
$messageStyle = '';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Sanitize and validate form fields
    $name = sanitizeInput($_POST["name"]);
    $email = sanitizeInput($_POST["email"]);
    $subject = sanitizeInput($_POST["subject"]);
    $message = sanitizeInput($_POST["message"]);

    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
        $messageStatus = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs obligatoires.";
        $messageStyle = "error";
    }

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $messageStatus = "E-mail non valide.";
        $messageStyle = "error";
    }

    // Create an instance of ContactForm and send the email
    $contactForm = new ContactForm($name, $email, $subject, $message);
    if ($contactForm->sendEmail()) {
        $messageStatus = "E-mail envoyé avec succès!";
        $messageStyle = "success";
    } else {
        $messageStatus = "Error d'envoi!";
        $messageStyle = "error";
    }
}

/**
 * Sanitize the input data.
 *
 * @param string $data The input data to sanitize.
 * @return string The sanitized input data.
 */
function sanitizeInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

// Create the response array
$response = array(
    'success' => ($messageStyle === 'success'),
    'message' => $messageStatus
);

// Send the response as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

and my script that I have in 'public/js/custom.js' to handle the success/error messages:

```
// FORM


// Get the form element
var form = document.getElementById("contact-form");

// Get the message container element
var messageContainer = document.querySelector(".message-status");

// Function to display the message and hide after a delay
function showMessage(message, messageType) {
    var messageContainer = $("#messageContainer");
    messageContainer.removeClass("alert-success alert-danger");
    
    if (messageType === "success") {
        messageContainer.addClass("alert-success");
    } else {
        messageContainer.addClass("alert-danger");
    }
    
    messageContainer.text(message);
    messageContainer.fadeIn("slow", function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        messageContainer.fadeOut("slow");
        }, 4000);
    });
    }

// Function to handle form submission
function submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting traditionally

    // Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Define the AJAX request
    xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    // Handle the AJAX response
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
            try {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (response.success) {
                    showMessage(response.message, "success");
                } else {
                    showMessage(response.message, "error");
                }
            } catch (error) {
                showMessage("Failed to parse the server response.", "error");
            }
        } else {
            showMessage("Failed to send the form data.", "error");
        }
    };

    // Send the AJAX request with the form data
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
}

// Add event listener for form submission
if (form && messageContainer) {
    form.addEventListener("submit", submitForm);
}
```

Comment: You have not shown what you mean by "messes up". Your form's action of `action="../app/config/contact.php"` looks wrong – a browser should not be able to directly access scripts outside your web root (which should be `public/`). I'm also not sure what `.htaccess` has to do with any of this.

Comment: so, how should I proceed in the 'action' to execute the contact.php?

Comment: If you want to have `contact.php` as an endpoint of your appliaction (e.g. form action, xhr target), it needs to be accessible from the browser, that is in _public_. There is no requirement for .htaccess here strictly speaking. You may want to optimize that, but beforehand you should make it functional first. Use it as an opportunity to also have _public_ as the webroot in your local environment. That will also help you to add .htaccess magic later on.

Comment: For example: `<form ... action="contact.php" ...>`.

Comment: that I already did, but what I learned in school is to always try to keep files with this things in out of the public folder, so they are not accessible to the general public.
It works like this here, but as soon as I put the public to open as default with the .htaccess the form stops working.

Comment: “ that makes the website start automatically from the index.php” - what do you mean by that? You shouldn't need to add anything. What .htaccess directives are you attempting to use?

Comment: Yes, this is why I called it an _endpoint_ (also _entrypoint_). So, when it works, you remove all library code from it and only include the autoloader so that the code in the (so-called) transaction script is reduced as you learned it in school and only contains the necessary minimum (this also makes a transaction script easier to read). Things that should _never_ be in _public_  for example is the _vendor_ folder, the config files, library code and the .git folder. And depending on the design/architecture of your application a larger or smaller part of the application code as well.

Comment: @hakre can you give me a tutorial or somewhere where I can see how to do that?
I feel that what you are talking is a file that loads automatically all the others like I already used in laravel for example, but I want to be sure

Comment: You're on the right track. Laravel as a Framework dictates these aspects. You find there the autoloading for example and IIRC some .htaccess "magic" so that its up-front-controlling of all incomming requests are routed within the application. Therefore within Laravel you (commonly) have only a single entrypoint. Here you may not use a framework, therefore you can do your own design. If I get your level of understanding right, the "tutorial" is to first get `contact.php` working. Then configure your local environment it comes close to the webserver online.  Then you can play with the .htaccess.

Comment: And a hint: Laravel is open source. So you can have a second project based on Laravel that is not doing much and you use it to read its code and configuration and then for example investigate how their .htaccess works with _public_, the index.php entrypoint etc. and learn from that.