# ReactJS and PHP: fetching PHP file doing a curl

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch-api, php-curl

My main application runs on port 4000 and I have another application running on my localhost that uses port 5000 (= the app I want to fetch data from). I want to develop my app now to migrate to a productive-instance.

Now in my frontend I am trying to fetch data via a PHP that curls to my other application.

Somehow I always get a **404-Not-Found** response.

### Structure of my application:

```
my-app
  - backend
    - curlfile.php
  - frontend
    - fileWithFetch.js
```

### Snippet from `fileWithFetch.js`:

```
const getFromAPI = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`backend/curlfile.php`);
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }

}
```

*Note:* when I call the running app on port 5000 directly within the `fetch('localhost:5000/api-route')` then it runs fine.

### Minimal example (just for a simple testing) of `curlfile.php`:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$array = ["test"    => "My-Content"];
echo json_encode($array);
```

Thank you for sharing suggestions or specific approaches with me.

Comment: Have you considered the URL being used in your ```fetch()``` ? you have to be sure of how Absolute and Relative URLs affect where the ```fetch()``` API is looking at. Approaches like leading with  and without forward slash ```fetch('/backend/curlfile.php')```  or just using a full domain fetch

Comment: Or relative path: `../backend/curlfile.php` - requires more understanding but IMHO worth to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your responses... hm, even if I use the absolute path `/home/<user>/Desktop/my-app/backend/curlfile.php` it doesn't work and I get a 404 - not found.

Comment: If I move the file to `public/` then the fetching works. But this file is meant to contain sensible information - what are my options now?

Comment: endpoints need to be in public. but then they can require different files not in public. is it this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I want to fetch from a 'private' php-file, that isn't visible/accessible from the clients. So my frontend should somehow trigger and execute the `curlfile.php` and the clients should only be aware of the result.

Comment: Yes and no. curlfile.php must be publicly accessible from the clients, otherwise the client has no endpoint to talk to. However that curlfile.php must not be the curlfile.php you currently have. Compare with another Q&A where this has been discussed recently: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76681260/367456